# mysql sum all columns separately

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

*I don't know why they closed my old question,there was only one question. I edited it but no one returned. Anyway, my question was this:*

I have a table with about 50 columns. Most of them are integer and double but some are string. I want to sum all int and double columns separately in sql.

I know I can do it like this:

```
select sum(x), sum(y), sum(z) ..... from table_name
```

But i do not want to write sum(column_name) 50 times.

you know any solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Believe me - nothing has changed in the past 19 hours.

Comment: You didn't comment on the posted answer to your previous question - was there some problem with it?

Comment: @P.Salmon 
there was only one clear answer in the comments on my previous question and yes it didn't solve my problem

Comment: If it didn't you should have articulated why as a comment to the answer so that the answerer had the opportunity to tweak their answer and to indicate to the community that the answer was not appropriate - which would have helped keep the question open. Nb the answer looked correct to me..If you wish to comment in your original question you may get he post reopened (I have already voted so)

Comment: @Akina ok i will write it 50 times. i believe you :)